# My ISP hijacks my traffic even if I am using secure DNS

Tags: dns, dd-wrt, dnsmasq, dnscrypt

Some times, when I enter a page in the first days of the month, I get redirected to a "Here's your bill page".

I set up secure DNS but today it happened again.

Is there a way I can avoid this? 
This is my DD-WRT config

[image]

EDIT: The ISP is Movistar (Telefónica de Argentina)
I am redirected to an IP, and indeed the target was non https. The following is the registry from Firefox after clicking on afip.gob.ar Google result

http://3.3.3.3/redirect.html?CPURL=http://www.afip.gob.ar/572web/carga-datos/deducciones.asp%3f

Comment: Can you please name and shame your ISP so we'll all know what ISP to never, ever use under any circumstances? Have you tried seeing if your ISP lets you opt out of this idiocy?

Comment: Why are you assuming it's DNS hijacking? If you're not using TLS (secure HTTPS) everywhere, your ISP can intercept your insecure HTTP connections and serve you whatever content they want. Just like Wi-Fi captive portal networks do. Captive portals do not rely on DNS hijacking, they just do insecure HTTP hijacking.

Comment: Your ISP is not really hijacking your traffic.  Your ISP due to it being your DNS provider is able to show you a page similar to that of a captive portal.  Since you are using DD-WRT you can change the DNS provider and avoid this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound did you see the DD WRT config page?

Comment: The ISP could redirect all port 53 traffic to their DNS servers, ignoring your configured DNS servers.